# Calculating errors between two strings in Java

Tags: java, string, edit-distance

I would like to calculate the percentage of error between two strings, that means if we assume that one string is the ground truth and the other string is a typed string, then I would like to calculate the number of mistakes in the typed string.

Let's make an example:

```
ground truth = "This is a test"
typed = " Thisi is atest"
```

In `typed` there are 2 errors (additional i and missing space).

I think this can be done using some distance metric. Is there a library in Java for calculating such an error rate?

Comment: *"Is there a library?"* [Questions asking us to recommend or find a software library is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It is implemented in Apache Commons Text library:

See here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/

And here: https://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-text/jacoco/org.apache.commons.text.similarity/LevenshteinDistance.java.html